# Marklogic 9.0-3 REST Parameters accessing in REST extensions

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a REST extension and I have beeing accessing the parameters that have been passed, both in GET and POST as follows.. The parameters are passed as `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`. In my REST extension I would access the parameters via `xdmp:get-request-field("remoteURL")`.

In ML-8, this worked where in when calling the WS I would pass in the parameters as `remoteURL` and it worked..

Now in ML-9.0-3, it does not work, so I tried passing the parameters via `rs:remoteURL` and access in the REST extension as `xdmp:get-request-field("remoteURL")` and it fails, but when I access as `xdmp:get-request-field("rs:remoteURL")`. it works.. Did this got changed in ML-9.0-3 ?

Just for complete I am including my REST extension code as well

```
declare function repoTest:post($context as map:map, $params  as map:map,$input   as document-node()*) as document-node()*
{
  let $_ := xdmp:log("Inside the Repo Test POST")
  let $remoteURL :=xdmp:get-request-field("remoteURL")
  let $_ := xdmp:log($remoteURL)
  let $output := json:object()
  let $_ :=  map:put($output, "remoteURL", $remoteURL)
  return document { xdmp:to-json($output) }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a change in this, though it could be very well possible. I'd recommend accessing parameters via the $params map:map, which is the recommended way for REST extensions anyhow. $params will always contains any rs: request parameters without the rs: prefix.

HTH!

Comment: Can I use map params to get the binary content and filename etc

Comment: I never tried to be honest. I suspect currently not. At least not with form-data. I think it should be able to handle multipart/mixed though.

Answer (score 1):

The documented approach has always been to use the rs: prefix for user-defined parameters.

If parameters without the prefix were provided to the extension, that was unexpected.

Hoping that clarifies,